# How to set pageX for simulated Javascript event

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, mousemove

I'm simulating a `mousemove` event on a DOM node by:

```
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
e.initEvent('mousemove', true, true)
node.dispatchEvent(e)
```

However in my `mousemove` callback which is bound on the document, the event object is returned with a `pageX` of 0. Is there a way I can set `pageX` when initializing or dispatching the event?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.initMouseEvent):

To see it working, just run this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { console.log(e.pageX); });
var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
// event.initMouseEvent(type, canBubble, cancelable, view, detail, screenX, screenY, clientX, clientY)...
e.initMouseEvent('mousemove', true, true, window, 1, 100, 100, 100, 100);
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Seems that `clientX` and `clientY` are the same as `pageX` and `pageY`!
Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately `initMouseEvent` is deprecated. [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) seems like a better choice.