# How can I animate a series of mouse events to look like the mouse moves from point A to point B?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To be clear, I'm not talking about visually making it look like the mouse is moving from point A to point B. As a proof of concept regarding a friend's captcha system, I want to replicate the behavior of a mouse moving from one point to another so that any event listeners (trying to check that the cursor moved to the target rather than just simply simulating a click) will be fooled.

What I'm having trouble with is how to animate a cursor's path manually. Consider this code using JQuery to simulate a `mousemove` event:

```
var $canvas = $('canvas');
var event = $.Event('mousemove');
event.clientX = //x coord
event.clientY = //y coord
$canvas.trigger(event);
```

I'm at a loss for how I would set the x and y coords in such a way as to animate from one coordinate to another.

How can this be done?

Comment: Deep digging shows a MouseEvent that may do what you want. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618426/how-to-set-pagex-for-simulated-javascript-event

Comment: look into elementFromPoint(), the rest is simpler

Comment: @dandavis I dont understand how that helps

Comment: maybe i'm getting ahead. once you realize the restrictions of dynamic created events, you'll see the need to be able to lookup the elm from a calculated half-way point of two coords.