# Setting click events pageX and pageY always reverts to 0

Tags: javascript

Not sure what I could be doing wrong, but I'm trying to simulate a click event by giving it a X and Y value.

Here is my code

```
var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent'),
    DOMbody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
    testX = targetJoint.depthX * DOMbody.clientWidth,
    testY = DOMbody.clientHeight - (targetJoint.depthY * DOMbody.clientHeight);

clickEvent.pageX = testX;
clickEvent.pageY = testY;

if (counter < 5000) {
    counter++;
    console.log('testX: ' + testX);
    console.log('testY: ' + testY);
    console.log('click event X: ' + clickEvent.pageX);
    console.log('click event Y: ' + clickEvent.pageY);
}

//}
clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

Where I am getting `testX` and `testY` is irrelevant. It's coming from Kinect data, and the console logs would look like this:

```
testX: 701.220
testY: 290.693
click event X: 0
click event Y: 0

testX: 704.132
testY: 291.669
click event X: 0
click event Y: 0

testX: 689.852
testY: 284.198
click event X: 0
click event Y: 0
```

So why would it be 0 even though I am clearly setting it with a proper value?

**EDIT** : although this isn't really the same data I'd get back, it would be impossible to recreate a fiddle with the kinect data coming in. Made this rough example on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ox8ueLxk/) to at least show that the click event pagex/y is 0 even when I'm explicitly setting it (on the fiddle for whatever reason the `testY` is 0 too, but the `testX` isnt and the `clickEvent.pageX` is 0)

Comment: Does this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618426/how-to-set-pagex-for-simulated-javascript-event

Comment: @Daniel nope doesn't look like it.

Comment: You're right, it's deprecated

Comment: What browsers are you targeting?

Comment: What about this then? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent It seems javascript has a constructor for mouse events `MouseEvent` there you can set a clientX and clientY!

Comment: It seems to be the same as `document.createEvent('MouseEvent')`, then `pageX` and `pageY` are not in the MDN's documentation! Although `pageX` and `pageY` are true properties from an event, they just don't seem to be present on MouseEvent

Comment: What is `targetJoint`?

Comment: @Daniel I mentioned it twice in my question, but it's data coming back from Kinect. It's irrelevant since I prove it has a value, so the issue is setting the pageX/Y. In my fiddle I also made a dummy object `targetJoint` which shows the same thing happening.

Comment: Well, `document.createEvent('MouseEvent')` and `MouseEvent` constructor are not actually the same, in fact, `MouseEvent` is not supported by some browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill

Comment: @Daniel you can't set the pageX/Y that way though

Comment: Exactly, you should pass them as a parameter to the constructor, something like `new MouseEvent('click', { clientX: 123, clientY: 456 })`, the problem now is that `MouseEvent` is not supported in some browsers!

Comment: Another possibility would be through [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) constructor, but it seems that its method [`.initEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) is also deprecated... There doesn't seem to be a way to properly do this without having to define polyfills

Comment: [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor also seem to have no support on Internet Explorer!

Comment: I don't really care about IE, we're working with Chrome anyways.

Comment: If that so, I already have an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found that MDN Documentation for creating Events have some holes on it, as it doesn't seem to show a reliable, cross-browser solution for simulating mouse events.

Anyway, I found that there are some ways to create a `MouseEvent` instance:

**Using** [`document.createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent):

```js
var mouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');

mouseEvent.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 100, 100, 100, 100);
```

This creates not only `.clientX` and `.clientY`, but also `pageX` and `pageY` as well, however, [as it's stated in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent), `.initMouseEvent` is deprecated.

**Using** [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill) **constructor**:

```js
var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
    clientX: 100,
    clientY: 100
});
```

`MouseEvent` doesn't support `pageX` and `pageY` properties, and it's also [not supported by Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Specifications)

In the `MouseEvent` constructor documentation, its said that for browsers who don't support `MouseEvent` constructor, [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent#Polyfill) should be used, which is currently creating the event with `document.createEvent('MouseEvent')` and using the deprecated `.initMouseEvent` method to initialize it...

**What I don't get was the fact that the polyfill does not accept arguments for all properties except for** `.bubbles` **and** `.cancelable` *(i.e: `.screenX`, `.screenY`, `.clientX` and `.clientY` are not accepted as well)*, if you use the polyfill you should add the properties you need to it, to do that you just need to check how `.bubbles` and `.cancelable` properties are being setted.

So the ultimate solution should be using that polyfill *(which I'm not showing here since it can be changed later on)* and then create the method just by *instantiating* `MouseEvent`:

```js
// vars
var counter = 0,
    DOMfoo = document.getElementById('foo'),
    targetJoint = {
        depthX: 0.5,
        depthY: 0.3,
    };
    
// functions
function simulateEvent (eventType, node) {  
    var DOMbody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        testX = targetJoint.depthX * DOMbody.clientWidth,
        testY = DOMbody.clientHeight - (targetJoint.depthY * DOMbody.clientHeight),
        clickEvent = new MouseEvent('test', {
            clientX: testX,
            clientY: testY
        });

    if (counter < 5000) {
        counter++;
        console.log('testX: ' + testX);
        console.log('testY: ' + testY);
        console.log('click event X: ' + clickEvent.clientX);
        console.log('click event Y: ' + clickEvent.clientY);
    }

    clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
    node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}

// init
simulateEvent('click', DOMfoo);
```

```html
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
```